# Changing posts order on a page

Tags: order

I have a template that has a dedicated page for STAFF.  The only problem is, I can't rearrange the entries.  In other words, all the entries are automatically sorted based on time when the data was entered.  Is there a way to manually change the order of these entries.  For example, if I want to move my secretary on spot up or down on the page.
Here is the staff page template:

```
<?php if (!defined('ABSPATH')) die('No direct access allowed'); ?>
<?php
/*
  Template Name: Staff-Page
 */

get_header();

global $post;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'staff-page',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 5
));
?>

<ul class="team">

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <li>

                <div class="four columns">

                    <div class="bordered">
                        <figure class="add-border">
                            <img src="<?php echo ThemeMakersHelper::get_post_featured_image($post->ID, 204, false, 174); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                        </figure>
                    </div><!--/ .bordered-->

                </div><!--/ .four .columns-->

                <div class="twelve columns">

                    <?php $positions = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'position'); ?>
                    <h4 class="with-desc" data-desc="( <?php
                    foreach ($positions as $item)
                        echo $item->name . ' ';
                    ?>)">

                        <?php the_title(); ?></h4>

                    <?php the_content() ?>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    <?php $email = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'staff_email', true); ?>
                    <?php if (!empty($email)): ?>
                        <br />
                        <a href="mailto:<?php echo $email ?>" class="button default small"><?php _e('E-mail', TMM_THEME_FOLDER_NAME); ?> <?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div><!--/ .twelve .columns-->

            </li>

            <?php
        endwhile;
    endif;
    ?>  

</ul>

<?php get_template_part('content', 'pagenavi'); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Please format your code properly so other could easily read it.

Answer (score 0):

posts, in descending order by the title:
this is a format of post order by it's title to add title

```
query_posts( array( 'category__and' => array(1,3), 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
```

And it's your code want change

```
global $post;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'staff-page',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'title'
    'posts_per_page' => 5
));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a custom post type, the simplest thing would be to add "page-attributes" to your post capabilities. Then you can order them any way you want.

1. Add 'page-attributes' to the array where you register the post type.
   example:
   'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor' , 'page-attributes', 'thumbnail' )
2. Then your query would be:

   ```
   global $post;
   $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
   query_posts(array(
      'post_type' => 'staff-page',
      'paged' => $paged,
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'orderby' => 'menu_order'
      'posts_per_page' => 5
   ));
   ```